# margin issue in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a margin issue in Firefox which totally works in other browsers so, this is my HTML

HTML:

//*** means some code

```
<header>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="logo">
            //***
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div id="log-on">
            //***
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
<section class="search-seaction">
    //***    
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.clear { clear:both; }

.left { float: left }

.right { float: right }

.search-seaction
{
    margin-top: 62px;        
}
```

and here is screenshots

Firefox:
[image]

Opera & Chrome:
[image]

That margin over header appears only in Firefox. What is the reason of that behavior?

**ISSUE** : when I give margin to section, the header is "margining"

Comment: The bits of the HTML you have omitted are probably significant. If you can, post a link to it.

Comment: I developed it in localhost, I have not any links

Comment: Maybe if you use a css reset, you'll get rid of this strange behavior

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset ? Browsers have different defaults for margin, padding, etc...

Comment: I have already used css reset

Comment: This question has probably been asked 100 times before.

Comment: @Alerty yeah this is 101 time, and I hope i will finally ge the answer

Comment: seems like a bug in firefox, it just duplicates the margin on the previous element, verrry strange - ramblex's solution seems like a good workaround, however

Comment: You could replace all those divs with sections! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try giving the header a height:

```
header {
  height: 100px;
}
```

(setting the overflow to hidden works too)

```
header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. Setting the height to 100% worked beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also fix it by using another clearfix:

http://jsfiddle.net/dXskZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code into your css

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

OR

```
html,body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

or both

Comment: Than please provide live url or html and css

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does happen. To solve it, you can use a reset style sheet. [Reset Stylesheet sample](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

instead of  i used Css: `overflow: auto` for header, it is working. But I can't reply why